# ChromeDriver : driver failed to parse value of getElementRegion - understanding the error

Tags: protractor, chromedriver, chrome

The chrome on my office Mac machine recently updated to 76+. Since then one of the tests, written in Protractor and CucumberJS, started failing to cite this error -

```
WebDriverError: unknown error: failed to parse value of getElementRegion
     (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.87)
```

I managed to fix the error since the element in the DOM was actually changed by the FE developer (on the same day the update occurred) and changing the locator fixed the test case. However, I'm curious why I got this error and not `ElementNotFoundException` or `NoSuchElementException`  instead.

Googling this doesn't result in a lot of answers and as to what this error actually refers to. The only links that I got were from the ChromeDriver code, and it appears in line 587 here -

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/test/chromedriver/element_util.cc

A similar question asked on SO a couple of years back has no answers - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977672/selenium-chrome-driver-failed-to-parse-value-of-getelementregion)

Looking to get more answers from the community around this error and what is the cases when this error should come.

Comment: I've gotten that error using selenium-standalone, then I gone for webdriver-manager and everything gone well.

Comment: Where is the stacktrace? Virtually there is no information provided on the element which caused this issue in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and solved it by deleting the line
`SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false`
in my conf.js file on my protractor configuration.

Comment: An explanation of why this worked would make this answer more useful.

Answer (score 0):

For me this Error occured because I was not accessing the real element, but it's shadow DOM instance instead. The element exists, thus no `NoSuchElementException` but it is not visible. Resolve this by using 
`$$(YOUR_SELECTOR).get(INDEX_OF_REAL_ELEMENT)`

Comment: Just a note that I encountered the "driver failed to parse value of getElementRegion" under similar circumstances. I was using a selector that matched both what I wanted (an `h1`) and, unexpectedly, the header's `title` element. I fixed the selector to match only the `h1` and the error went away.